# Wordpress visual editor breaks automatically to new line

Tags: wordpress

Hope you are all fine. I have been facing an issue with wordpress visual editor which dont allow me to type full line in a row the text automatically shifts to new line when the paragraph or text reaches to the middle of editor i have searched a lot but didn't find solution to it kindly help me solving this issue.
Following are the screen shot:

[image]

Note: I have found this problems with the new version of wordpress in old versions it allow me write fully in visual editor. i install wordpress several time for several different projects but all have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following function to your WordPress functions.php file

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

[Here are the link for WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)